# Remote Debugging with Vue-Devtools Shell - net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: socket.io, vuejs2, remote-debugging, vue-devtools

I’ve been trying to set up a mobile development environment for Vue.js using the command line ‘vue-devtools’ command. To access my localhost on the mobile device, I have set up reverse-tethering between my desktop and mobile.

The ‘Vue Developer Tools’ window is stuck on the ‘Waiting for connection…’ and 'Add : ’ page, and in the Chrome devtools I am receiving the error:

‘GET http://localhost:8098/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MWodKWT net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED’

...every 5-7 seconds.

I have read through all the docs and repo conversations, and looked for similar issues here on SO. I have never used nor do I know anything about SocketIO, and I am not using it in my project. It is implemented in the Vue-devtools shell so 
I don’t even know how to begin debugging this.

I will provide any additional information needed, and clean up the question to better suit the format once I know what is going on. (It's hard to keep the format when I'm flailing in the dark)